# VNC on Ubuntu 23.04 - recompiled gnome-remote-desktop but still failed

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, vnc, 23.04

First I read the post on: [GNOME Screen Sharing VNC 23.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469028/gnome-screen-sharing-vnc-23-04)

Thanks to that I got what I needed to do, then I have tried to rebuild the **gnome-remote-desktop** package enabling the VNC. Some dependencies issues occurred on my OrangePi5 - took me a while but I worked it out with some manual installs and downgrades of a few packages.

So anyway finally I rebuilt the gnome-remote desktop package via `debuild -uc -us -b -i`. Package installed successfully thereafter with `dpkg -i`.

I restarted the OrangePi5, everything starts as normal, and I was ecstatic to find that I can issue the "grdctl vnc enable" command without an error. But after I found out I can't connect to it :( I also did an `nmap -p5900 localhost` scan and found that the **port 5900 is closed**.

Any hints as to where I should look next? VNC is really important to me because I want to remote control the computer and I use wayland. I prefer not having to move to x11 as wayland works way faster on this OrangePi5.

Thanks in advance. Much appreciated.

Comment: Workaround: Use RealVNC https://www.realvnc.com/en/ It is free. Otherwise, use RDP to remote control

Comment: Thanks, I installed RealVNC and it works like a charm as espected, but still it means I have to switch between Wayland to X11 when I want to control remotely. I liked the times when gnome-remote-desktop used to work in 22.04, where I can just control my Wayland desktop as is.

I wish there is a way we can re-enable that built-in VNC in gnome-remote-desktop.

Comment: By the way, I can't get RDP to work, I end up with that screen where I was able to input the username and password, and a few selections were available, one of them being "Xorg". But no matter which selection I made, after I input username and password I get a blank screen. I read online that this method requires the primary screen to be logged off, so that's not ideal either. I want to control the screen I'm on, not a virtual session.

Comment: Unless you have a touch screen/convertible, there is almost no benefit of wayland. Wayland has issues with screen sharing and certain graphics cards. Just use XOrg

Comment: For some reason, whether that is hardware acceleration or something else, my desktop experience (GNOME) just runs faster with Wayland as opposed to XOrg. I started out with the OrangePi5's Ubuntu release 22.04 before upgrading to 23.04 through Software Updater. Xorg just produces more screen tearing, and overall just less smooth compared to the Wayland alternative. I'm trying to live with it now though, VNC is just too important for me.

Comment: Alternatively (since Orange Pi is not a very powerful device), use MATE Desktop or XFCE. They are way more lightweight compared to GNOME

Comment: Actually when I'm trying to play a video through MPV I get an error message "Unsupported hwdec: rkmpp". This could be another thing that is causing an issue? Will have to investigate when I get the chance. Thanks for your help! At least I can get back to how things used to be with Xorg.

Comment: I have no idea about the MPV issue, but you can ask a new question

Comment: I am rewriting my previous comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RealVNC https://realvnc.com/en. It is free. Also, there you can sign in, and access the computer from anywhere, including your smartphone.