# Remote Desktop - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, rdp

I run Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Remote Desktop that is built in and it is great! (see attached image)
However, when my internet connection breaks the service seems to hang up and I need to reboot the computer in order to be able to connect again.
The normal sshd always works even after a connection issue so I wonder how do I:
Reset this service from command line?

It seems to me that just resetting it will work but I don't know what service it is...
Thanks for any suggestion :-)

[image]

Comment: RDP by default, I believe. And the toggle for Legacy VNC = VNC. Have you been able to get this to work? VNC via Remoter on MacOS fails for me, as well as RDP via Microsoft Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

This works on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3. The default Remote Desktop is gnome-remote-desktop and can be enabled via the terminal with:

```
grdctl rdp enable
```

or conversely disable with

```
grdctl rdp disable
```

Check status with

```
grdctl rdp status
```

As I was looking for a solution for myself I came across this post regarding vnc/rdp here stating that future releases will no longer support vnc (doesn’t seem to be an issue for you but might be helpful for anyone stumbling across this in the future - and vnc is no longer supported as of 23.04):

[GNOME Screen Sharing VNC 23.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469028/gnome-screen-sharing-vnc-23-04/1469127#1469127)

Also I didn’t find out that the Remote Desktop Server was switched to Gnome Remote Desktop from Vino until yesterday as the Ubuntu documentation (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers) still has Vino listed as the default server.

Initially I used *vnc* and changed it to *rdp* in the command to be relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: Status command is just `grdctl status`, no rdp

Answer (score -1):

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on Windows 11 using Hyper-V. The steps to enable RDP Ubuntu VM are very staright forward.

1. Start, Connect and Logged on Ubuntu VM from Hyper V
2. In Ubuntu open Settings and then clik Sharing.
   [image]
3. Enable/ON the Sharing in title bar near minimize button and click Remote Desktop.
4. On Remote Desktop dialog/screen/page Enable/On Remote Desktop and Remote Control.
5. Note the Remote Desktop Address. My Ubuntu address is ms-rd://ubuntu224.local
6. Also note the User Name and Password
   [image]
7. Now on your Windows 11 open Remote Desktop Connection.
   [image]
8. Type "ubuntu224.local" Computer in computer box. Type the User name and password. It will RDP you to your Ubuntu VM. Hope this will help.

Comment: The asker already stated that they know how to reset (disable then enable (like you are describing in your answer)) the screen sharing. They are looking for a way that does not involve that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).